# Nginx not rendering puma application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, puma

I'm trying to serve my rails application using Puma and Nginx. When ever I got to the page it renders the default nginx page. I've tried with two different configurations. This first fails with  `"upstream" directive is not allowed here.` The second warns `Starting nginx: nginx: [warn] conflicting server name "localhost" on 0.0.0.0:80, ignored`

## (1) overwrite nginx.conf

#### nginx.conf

```
upstream puma {
  server unix:///home/deploy/apps/exelon-api/shared/tmp/sockets/rails-api-puma.sock;
}
server {
  listen 80 default_server deferred;
  # server_name example.com;
  root /home/deploy/apps/rails-api/current/public;
  access_log /home/deploy/apps/rails-api/current/log/nginx.access.log;
  error_log /home/deploy/apps/rails-api/current/log/nginx.error.log info;
  location ^~ /assets/ {
    gzip_static on;
    expires max;
    add_header Cache-Control public;
  }
  try_files $uri/index.html $uri @puma;
  location @puma {
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    proxy_redirect off;
    proxy_pass http://puma;
  }
  error_page 500 502 503 504 /500.html;
  client_max_body_size 10M;
  keepalive_timeout 10;
}
```

## (2) using sites enabled

#### nginx.conf

```
user nginx;
worker_processes  1;
error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log;
pid        /var/run/nginx.pid;
events {
  worker_connections  1024;
}
http {
  include       /etc/nginx/mime.types;
  default_type  application/octet-stream;
  access_log    /var/log/nginx/access.log;
  sendfile on;
  tcp_nopush on;
  tcp_nodelay on;
  keepalive_requests 100;
  keepalive_timeout  65;
  gzip  on;
  gzip_http_version 1.0;
  gzip_comp_level 2;
  gzip_proxied any;
  gzip_vary off;
  gzip_types text/plain text/css application/x-javascript text/xml application/xml application/rss+xml application/atom+xml text/javascript application/javascript application/json text/mathml;
  gzip_min_length  1000;
  gzip_disable     "MSIE [1-6]\.";
  variables_hash_max_size 1024;
  variables_hash_bucket_size 64;
  server_names_hash_bucket_size 64;
  types_hash_max_size 2048;
  types_hash_bucket_size 64;
  include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
  include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
}
```

#### sites-enable/rails-api_production

```
upstream puma_rails-api_production { 
  server unix:/home/deploy/apps/rails-api/shared/tmp/sockets/rails-api-puma.sock fail_timeout=0;
}
server {
  listen 80;
  client_max_body_size 4G;
  keepalive_timeout 10;
  error_page 500 502 504 /500.html;
  error_page 503 @503;
  server_name localhost rails-api.local;
  root /home/deploy/apps/rails-api/current/public;
  try_files $uri/index.html $uri @puma_rails-api_production;
  location @puma_rails-api_production {
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    proxy_redirect off;
    proxy_pass http://puma_rails-api_production;
    # limit_req zone=one;
    access_log /home/deploy/apps/rails-api/shared/log/nginx.access.log;
    error_log /home/deploy/apps/rails-api/shared/log/nginx.error.log;
  }
  location ^~ /assets/ {
    gzip_static on;
    expires max;
    add_header Cache-Control public;
  }
  location = /50x.html {
    root html;
  }
  location = /404.html {
    root html;
  }
  location @503 {
    error_page 405 = /system/maintenance.html;
    if (-f $document_root/system/maintenance.html) {
      rewrite ^(.*)$ /system/maintenance.html break;
    }
    rewrite ^(.*)$ /503.html break;
  }
  if ($request_method !~ ^(GET|HEAD|PUT|PATCH|POST|DELETE|OPTIONS)$ ){
    return 405;
  }
  if (-f $document_root/system/maintenance.html) {
    return 503;
  }
  location ~ \.(php|html)$ {
    return 405;
  }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried deleting the `default.conf` in sites-enabled?

Comment: @CWitty Yes its been removed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Second error practically says that you have two `server` sections defined with `listen 80` (which practically means `0.0.0.0:80` where `0.0.0.0` is equal to "any address") and `localhost` in `server_name`.

So, action you have to take depends on what you want to achieve:

## Have some other app as default

If you want to have **your app to be accessible alongside some other apps you have (or want to have in future) on server by some hostname**, let's say `example.com`, you have to simply remove `localhost` from `server_name` in the entry you added.

In this case, you will have to access your app by one of the names you have specified for it in `server_name` ( `example.com`), neither `localhost` nor server IP.

**Note** that if you still have to make sure domain you've specified resolves to the server address.

**If it is on your own local machine** and you want to be able to access your app for development purposes (testing how it works with nginx, for example) you can
 add row `127.0.0.1 name.here` (for example, `127.0.0.1 example.com`).

If it is **on some server you own** and you want others to be able to access app by the same domain, you have to buy/register it (if it has not been registered by someone else yet, it happens) and create the `A` DNS record pointing to your app server IP.

## Make your app default

If you want this app **to be default on the server**, you can:

1. Find other `server` sections defined with `listen 80 default;` (so, if they don't have `default` or listen any other port like 8080 or 443 you can safely leave them) and remove the `default` from there - there can be only one default server section per port and IP combination.
2. Change `listen 80;` in your server section to `listen 80 default;`. This will tell nginx that you want this server section to handle all requests not catched by other section.

This will allow you to access app by IP and point any domain to it without specifying it in `server_name` section. You still need to register or buy domain to be able to point it to app.

Comment: I've removed the server_name as you first suggest but its still not working, it still shows the default nginx page. I'm not exactly sure what you are suggesting in your update.

Comment: Also, have you restarted server after changes?

Comment: Yes its been restarted. I dont have access to local. `curl: (6) Couldn't resolve host '45.55.206.214.local'`

Comment: @AntarrByrd oh, you will have to add it to the `/etc/hosts` to make sure it resolves to `127.0.0.1`

Comment: like so `127.0.0.1 local` ?

Comment: `127.0.0.1 rails-api.local`

Comment: It already has these two lines there. Should I leave them? `127.0.0.1   localhost localhost.localdomain localhost4 localhost4.localdomain4` and `::1         localhost localhost.localdomain localhost6 localhost6.localdomain6`

Comment: I don't want to have to actually go to `45.55.206.214.local` it should just render at `45.55.206.214/`

Comment: OK, I think the answer needs more explanation. I will try to post update tomorrow. If someone else would post better answer or edit my to add explanation how `server_name` works, I would not mind. :)

Comment: Ok thanks. Don't mind the wait, wife sending me to walmart

Comment: @AntarrByrd Updated.

Comment: Thanks Nginx appears to be working now, it gives me a 502 error my guess is its a Puma probolem. Will create a new question for that.